# Cocoa Finder app List view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder

Being a starter in Cocoa Programming, I would like to know using the existing `NSTableView` can one be able to achieve `Disclosure` Button? Or one has to follow `NSOutlineview`?

[image]

From the above picture, on selecting the list view and getting a Folder[Super view] and getting the children using a Disclosure button

Also can a registered Mac Developer get Finder app's sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSOutlineView` is just a subclass of NSTableView, so yes just use `NSOutlineView` to use the disclosure button.

Check out the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/OutlineView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000023i) for how to use it.

And no, Apple never released the source code for Finder.

Comment: Thanks about the fact on finder app.